# Kubernetes pod created in istio enabled namespace entering NotReady state

Tags: kubernetes, istio, containerd

Using `kubernetes` `1.21` and `istio` `1.11.3`

I have an `istio`-enabled namespace, into which I create the following `Pod` via `kubectl create -f mypod.yaml` where `mypod.yaml` as below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: command-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["printenv"]
    args: ["HOSTNAME", "KUBERNETES_PORT"]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

The pod ends up in a `NotReady` state

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
command-demo                                    1/2     NotReady     0          41m
```

Why is this happening?

My assumption is that this could be related to the following `containerStatuses`

```yaml
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: containerd://121a8cb31bed60048116d45d0c500d5e3e11e41d790cdc4b506d37a9cb036e4f
    image: docker.io/library/debian:latest
    imageID: docker.io/library/debian@sha256:2906804d2a64e8a13a434a1a127fe3f6a28bf7cf3696be4223b06276f32f1f2d
    lastState: {}
    name: command-demo-container
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    started: false
    state:
      terminated:
        containerID: containerd://121a8cb31bed60048116d45d0c500d5e3e11e41d790cdc4b506d37a9cb036e4f
        exitCode: 0
        finishedAt: "2022-01-02T17:23:04Z"
        reason: Completed
        startedAt: "2022-01-02T17:23:04Z"
  - containerID: containerd://5d0defc42b32c62c421b8328b8d177c12a042ba98c4e666b96e999be569478bd
    image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.11.3
    imageID: docker.io/istio/proxyv2@sha256:28513eb3706315b26610a53e0d66b29b09a334e3164393b9a0591f34fe47a6fd
    lastState: {}
    name: istio-proxy
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2022-01-02T17:23:04Z"
  hostIP: 10.8.1.9
```

The (main) container exits, but the `istio` sidecar is still reported as running.

Is this behaviour normal / expected? Any way for a graceful pod shutdown in such `istio`-enabled namespaces / use-cases?

P.S. Why is `containerStatuses[0].started` = `false` since it is reported as `state.terminated` ?

Comment: Does your pod contain a health endpoint for istio? If it does not, then Istio might still be waiting for the pod to become ready https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/mesh/app-health-check/

If that is not the case, can you include the output of `kubectl describe pod [podname]`

Comment: Please let me know if you've found a way to stop the sidecar when other containers have stopped (pod status becomes NotReady). I have a similar issue with a helm pre-install,pre-upgrade hook (Pod) which is running HashiCorp vault as side-car.